# Can we share some contents of App.config between projects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two independent projects in my Visual Studio 2008 solution. Both has its own App.config. But in one project, I need one or two properties defined in another project's App.config. Is it possible to share part of the App.config contents from other project?

Comment: Ditto [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426245/how-to-share-app-config)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes - of course. Any configuration section can be "externalized" - e.g.:

```
<appSettings configSource="AppSettings.DEV.config" />
<connectionStrings configSource="MyConnection.config" />
```

or

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp configSource="smtp.TEST.config" />
```

vs.

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp configSource="smtp.PROD.config" />
```

Any configuration section can be put into a separate file that can be shared between projects - but no configuration section **groups**, and unfortunately, it's sometimes a bit tricky to know which is which.

Also, in some cases, Visual Studio will complain (using red wavy underlines) that the "configSource" supposedly isn't valid - but it is - it's defined on the `ConfigurationSection` object in the .NET config system.

**UPDATE:**
another feature that hardly enough developers seem to know and use is the ability in Visual Studio to add existing files from a different project **as a link**:

[image]

With this, you can add links to files into your local project, and they'll always be kept up to date. Great productivity booster if you need to do some file-level sharing (like for common configuration files or such)!

Comment: but the target file, such as "MyConnection.config" in your example, must be in the same directory or subdirectory?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: yes, it has to be in the same directory or a sub-directory thereof. It can be a "linked" file in Visual Studio, however - or a hard link on disk (NTFS link - a "pointer" to another file that looks and acts like "The Real Thing")

Comment: Hmmm... I wish I had though of mentioning linking. lol. but you left out something important, marc.

Comment: OK, I added it as a link, now how do I access the various values of the linked app config from the second project?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do as nawfal described as well.

Comment: @Justin: just as normal in .NET - just use the [ConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) ...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="PROD.config">
    <add key="common.Currency" value="GBP" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: yeah, but the "file=" attribute is only valid on the <appSettings> section - nothing else can be put into external files with that method.....

Answer (score 1):

Only the "running" app.config is used, but you can go external like marc_s says.

You can also create a .Settings file that's "shared".  Go to the "shared" project properties, the Settings tab on the left, create a setting with Application scope, and set the Access Modifier on top to Public.  In your other project you can then use ClassLibrary1.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName to access it.  It will be strongly typed, but you may need it at compile time.

Comment: But doesn't the Settings code that is generated rely on the app.config of the running up for persistence? Then you would still need a copy of that file for each running app.

Comment: @ProfK: Yes, you're right.  The .settings files can have default values which end up as `DefaultSettingValueAttribute` in code, unlike regular app settings in app.config.  However, any deviation from the default values would end up in each individual app.config.  Since the settings are stored in a section in app.config you could use a combination of the two and externalize it with configSource while keeping the compiled defaults and strong typing.  I guess it all depends what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Something I like to do, especially when trying to coordinate ServiceModel elements between libraries and tests is to use configSource to fragment the config in the target library and simply `link`/`copy always` the fragments in my test projects.

That way I only maintain in one location.

You could take it one step farther and simply have a common directory in the solution and link the fragments in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, I would think using a Database to store some configuration data would be ideal. Each app does its own thing, but they look to a shared database to get those common pieces of information.

**EDIT**: I spoke too soon! Looks like both the OP and I learned something about config files =D