# Is there a way to share a app.config between two projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a two projects under one solution, and I need to share a app.config file between them .
mostly they use the same parameters from the configuration.

Is there some way to share the config file ?
I am using VS2010.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Share App.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426245/how-to-share-app-config)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, just add the file from the other project 'as a link': Right click on the project >> select 'Add existing file' >> navigate to the app.config file >> click the dropdown next to the 'add' button and select 'add as a link'.

Comment: But how I can use it from the code ? When I try to use it like ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimulatorDB"].ConnectionString I  am getting an null exception

Comment: Oh I see that now you're trying to share _portions_ of app.config between projects. To achieve that, see this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746797/c-can-we-share-some-contents-of-app-config-between-projects . But in this case, you'll need to separate app.config files while one's sections pointing to the other (externalized) app.config file.

Comment: @Teoman Soygul , If I not going to use it, why will I add a reference to a app.config file :)

Comment: getting error - ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Cannot add a link to the file App.config. There is already a file of the same name in this folder.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Answer (score 3):

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555396

Hope this helps